# Calculate cardSum (Hands of Strings)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, blackjack

I am trying to create a Blackjack game. The game itself is pretty easy (at least my version). A player draws a card from a shuffled deck and calculates the sum of the cards which has been drawn. I have a decklist of cards with the type String and that is now a big problem for me. I have no clue how I can calculate the sum since they are of the type String. Do you have any guidelines on what I can do? The only solution I've figured out is really bad and is to compare the card with a String and give it a value. For example, `drawnCard.equals("Four of hearts") = "4";`

```
    public class Player {


    private String nickName;
    private int playerNumOfCards;
    ArrayList<Card> playerHand = new ArrayList<>();


    public Player (String name){
        this.nickName = name;
    }

    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void addCard(Card aCard){
        playerHand.add(aCard);
        this.playerNumOfCards++;

    }

    public void getHandSum(){

    }

    public void getPlayerHand(){
        for(Card cards: playerHand){
            System.out.println(cards.toString());
        }
    }


  }
```

```
    public class DeckOfCards {

    private Card[] deck;
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    private int currentCard; //index of next Card to be deal (0-51)
    private static int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 52; //Constant number of cards

    public DeckOfCards(){

        String [] faces = {"Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack","Queen", "King"};
        String [] suits = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};

        deck = new Card [NUMBER_OF_CARDS]; // create array with Cards (52)
        currentCard = 0;

        //Populate deck with Cards
        for(int count = 0; count < deck.length; count++)
            deck [count] = new Card(faces [count % 13], suits [count / 13]);
    }

    public void shuffleDeck(){
        currentCard = 0;

        for (int first = 0; first < deck.length; first++){

            int second = random.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_CARDS); //Select a random card from number 0-51 (Number_of_cards)

            //Loops through all the cards and swaps it with the "Second" card which is randomly chosen card from hte same list.
            Card temp = deck[first];
            deck [first] = deck [second];
            deck [second] = temp;
        }
    }

    public void getCardDeck(){
        int start = 1;
        for(Card k : deck) {
            System.out.println("" + start + "/52 " + k);
            start++;
        }
    }

    public Card dealNextCard(){

        //Get the top card
        Card topCard = this.deck[0];

        //shift all the subsequent cards to the left by one index
        for(int currentCard = 1; currentCard < NUMBER_OF_CARDS; currentCard ++){
            this.deck[currentCard-1] = this.deck[currentCard];
        }
        this.deck[NUMBER_OF_CARDS-1] = null;

        //decrement the number of cards in our deck
        this.NUMBER_OF_CARDS--;

        return topCard;
    }

}
```

```
    public class Card {
    private String face; //Face of card, i.e "King" & "Queen"
    private String suit; //Suit of card, i.e "Hearts" & "diamonds"

    public Card (String cardFace, String cardSuit){ //Constructor which initializes card's face and suit
        this.face = cardFace;
        this.suit = cardSuit;
    }

    public String toString(){ //return String representation of Card
        return face + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

```
 public class BlackJackGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DeckOfCards deck1 = new DeckOfCards();
        Player player1 = new Player("mille");
        deck1.shuffleDeck();

    }
}
```

Comment: Answer of this question will be dependent to what are you planing to do with the drawn cards. If you would like to have multiple contestants then maybe it's a better idea to consider implementing a "Hand" class that will evaluate it's own weight. Also the hand class should be easily compared to other Hands. Consider removing drawn cards from the deck and then adding them to player's Hand.

Comment: Strings are for people--computers do things with numbers. You'll save yourself a lot of headache and make your code a lot smaller and a lot faster if you represent cards as numbers, and only convert to strings for output.

Answer (score 2):

Create an enum to represent Face

```
enum Face {
    Ace(number), //I don't know what number is for Ace and others.
    Deuce(number),
    Three(3),
    Four(4),
    Five(5),
    Six(6),
    Seven(7),
    Eight(8),
    Nine(9),
    Ten(10),
    Jack(number),
    Queen(number),
    King(number);

    private final int number;

    Faces(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

Change type of face from String to Face.

```
class Card {

    private Face face;
    private String suit;

    public Card (Face cardFace, String cardSuit){card's face and suit
        this.face = cardFace;
        this.suit = cardSuit;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return face + " of " + suit;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return face.getNumber();
    }
}
```

Add a method to get the face number from card class and then use it accordingly. You will need to change other parts or your project as well but I will leave that for you to do.

Also suggest using enum for Suit.

Comment: This is one of the cases where I wish I could overload the + operator in Java.  I personally would be tempted to add a static factory method to `Card` to do the adding up, that way you aren't leaking the internals of `Card` but that might be over egging things.

Comment: Yeah, I know the pain :P Have worked with C# for 7 months and I liked that feature :) I went with the approach of not turning the card into a domain object. Would rather prefer getting them summed up via a service or something. But again it boils down to preference.

Comment: Yep, always more than one way.
Been exploring Swift, and that has operator overloading, I think in limited controlled ways it can be a very useful tool.

Comment: @Sneh First of all thanks for your answer. I have not been in touch with enums before but I've done some reading of them and I understand why and when we could/should use them. I am having some problems populating the deck with the new enums thp. Do I need setters I each enum "class" in order to set the values when I populate the deck?

Comment: Update: I fixed it. I simply replaced the values in the face and suit array in the DeckOfCards. Thanks again @Sneh

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see the deck list there, but if your card Strings always follow the same naming convention (i.e. "four of hearts") you could make your job a little easier by splitting each string by the " " space fields and then comparing the first word in the string to get the number (or corresponding 10 for king/queen etc..)

```
 String cardName = "four of hearts" (or whatever the variable name is);
   String[] parts = string.split(" ");
   String number = parts[0];
```

thus number would equal "four" only instead of having to compare "four of hearts" to return the number 4.

Hope that helps